# The limit of $ \ln{x} + \cot{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the following limit:$$\lim_{x \to \ 0^+} ({\ln{x} + \cot{x}})$$
I've tried to use L'Hôpital's rule, but  I can't transform the expression to the form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac {\infty }{\infty}$.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the function as
$$
\log x+\cot x=\frac{\sin x\log x+\cos x}{\sin x}.
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\sin x\log x=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot x\log x=0
$$
and the previous form is not indeterminate.

<sub>(Sorry, but I can't type “ln” for the logarithm.)</sub>

Comment: "\ln" gives you $\ln$ in $\TeX$.  I'm not familiar with MathJax, but I've heard it is similiar for simple expressions like this.

Comment: @StefanSmith I consider it perverse notation. `;-)`

Comment: @StefanSmith He meant that $\ln$ is gay and that $\log$ should be used.

Comment: @egreg : Got something against the French?  $\ln$ is good enough for Knuth, Graham, and Patashnik! ;)

Comment: @StefanSmith Unfortunately, the dreaded ln is imposing. I'll try resisting. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Using Taylor series

$$\ln x+\cot x=\frac{\sin x\ln x+\cos x}{\sin x}\sim_0\frac{x\ln x+1}{\sin x}\sim_0\frac{1}{\sin x}\to+\infty$$

Comment: You can only assert the first $\sim _0$ after proving that $\sin(x)\log(x)+\cos(x)\sim _0 x\log(x)+1$ and I don't think this is easy enough **not** to be explicitly mentioned and done.

Comment: Good to see you Sami. I am just red correcting many assignments. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$e^{\ln x + \cot x} = e^{\ln x}e^{\cot x} = xe^{\cot x} = \dfrac{x}{e^{-\cot x}}$$
This function is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ as $x \to 0^+$, so you can apply L'Hôpital's rule and derive the limit of $\ln x + \cot x$ from there.